# Cómo detectar posición Top y Bottom de un NestedScrollView en Android?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Con el evento `onNestedScroll` se puede detectar la posición relativa del scroll, no la absoluta

```
public class FabScrollBehavior extends FloatingActionButton.Behavior {

    public FabScrollBehavior(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet) {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNestedScroll(CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, FloatingActionButton child, View target, int dxConsumed, int dyConsumed, int dxUnconsumed, int dyUnconsumed) {

        super.onNestedScroll(coordinatorLayout, child, target, dxConsumed, dyConsumed, dxUnconsumed, dyUnconsumed);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onStartNestedScroll(CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, FloatingActionButton child, View directTargetChild, View target, int nestedScrollAxes) {
        return nestedScrollAxes == ViewCompat.SCROLL_AXIS_VERTICAL;
    }
}
```

Me estoy mirando la documentación oficial del [NestedScrollView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/NestedScrollView.html)

Me pregunto si es el mejor lugar para detectar si se está al inicio, final del scroll? o en el evento `onStopNestedScroll` que solo se lanza cuando el usuario a parado de hacer scroll, pero no veo si se puede leer la posición final, donde el usuario a dejado de hacer scroll.

En resume, detectar posición del scroll:

- Detectar si está al inicio.
- Detectar si está al final.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aporto mi propia solución:

Con el listener `setOnScrollChangeListener` se puede interceptar cuando hay algún cambio en el scroll de un `NestedScrollView`, y con el parámetro `scrollY` se puede leer el scroll absoluto como tambien el valor anterior con `oldScrollY`.

```
NestedScrollView scroller = (NestedScrollView) findViewById(R.id.myScroll);

        if (scroller != null) {

            scroller.setOnScrollChangeListener(new NestedScrollView.OnScrollChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onScrollChange(NestedScrollView v, int scrollX, int scrollY, int oldScrollX, int oldScrollY) {

                    if (scrollY > oldScrollY) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "Scroll DOWN");
                    }
                    if (scrollY < oldScrollY) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "Scroll UP");
                    }

                    if (scrollY == 0) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "TOP SCROLL");
                    }

                    if (scrollY == (v.getChildAt(0).getMeasuredHeight() - v.getMeasuredHeight())) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "BOTTOM SCROLL");
                    }
               }
            });
        }
```

con `v.getChildAt(0).getMeasuredHeight()` se obtiene la altura absoluta del contenido a mostrarse dentro del scroll.

con `v.getMeasuredHeight()` se obtiene la altura de ViewParent donde se muestra el contenido con scroll.